# Overloading unittestTestCase

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance

I have a module `myTest.py` in which I am going to overload the `unittest.TestCase` class. So in a testfile, tests are created like follows:

```
import myTest
class MyTest(myTest.MyTestCase):
    ...do something...
```

This works fine, but when I need other functionality from unittest, like `unittest.skip`, I also need to invoke `unittest` as well. I want to be able to invoke just `myTest.skip`, which should be a reference to `unittest.skip`. How can I achieve this behavior for every `unittest` attribute (except the inheritance from `unittest.TestCase`)? Is there another way instead doing `from unittest import *` in `myTest.py`?

Answer (score 3):

In `myTest.py`:

```
from unittest import skip
```

Then you can do:

```
import myTest

@myTest.skip(...)
class OtherTest(myTest.MyTestCase):
    ...
```

Comment: If he wants the whole namespace he can use `from unittest import *`, even though this kind of thing should be avoided.

Comment: Would it be ok in such a case to do a `from unittest import *`?

Comment: @Alex: We are all consenting adults, so as log as we are aware of the consequences - like namespace clashes - we are free to do what we feel is right.